# difference between composer update and composer dump-autoload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

sometime to update composer file.I use two different command `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`.

And both those have different result in command prompt like:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\rabble>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
```

**And:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\rabble>composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **composer update** always regenerates composer.lock and installs the lastest versions of available packages based on composer.json
>
> **composer dump-autoload** won’t download a thing. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project
> (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside
> your project

The above is sourced from [Robin Brackez, What does ‘composer dump-autoload’ do in Laravel?](https://web.archive.org/web/20141216130302/https://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/)

Comment: Just to clarify, there are at least 3 optimizations available for `dump-autoload`, which will either use the file-system (i.e. `PSR-4`), `APCu` (Alternative PHP Cache "for user") searching for new classes, or neither (i.e. "authoritative" or in the pre-generated classmap file mentioned only - `autoload_classmap.php`) depending on the desired environment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md . In production. it may result in significant performance difference.